# Get hard disk size in Python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, hard-drive

I am trying to get the hard drive size and free space using Python (I am using Python 2.7 with macOS).

I am trying with `os.statvfs('/')`, especially with the following code.
Is it correct what I am doing? Which definition of the variable `giga` shall I use?

```
import os

def get_machine_storage():
    result=os.statvfs('/')
    block_size=result.f_frsize
    total_blocks=result.f_blocks
    free_blocks=result.f_bfree
    # giga=1024*1024*1024
    giga=1000*1000*1000
    total_size=total_blocks*block_size/giga
    free_size=free_blocks*block_size/giga
    print('total_size = %s' % total_size)
    print('free_size = %s' % free_size)

get_machine_storage()
```

EDIT:
`statvfs` is deprecated in Python 3, do you know any alternative?

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274899/get-actual-disk-space) to see how to interpret the output.

Comment: @VasilisG. Thanks. I saw that the method is deprecated in Python 3, alternatives?

Comment: Try using `disk_usage` from `shutil` module.

Comment: Another question that might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260116/find-size-and-free-space-of-the-filesystem-containing-a-given-file

Answer (score 159, accepted):

### For Python 2 till Python 3.3

---

**Note**: As a few people mentioned in the comment section, this solution will work for **Python 3.3** and above. For **Python 2.7** it is best to use the [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) library, which has a [`disk_usage`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.disk_usage) function, containing information about **total**, **used** and **free** disk space:

```
import psutil

hdd = psutil.disk_usage('/')

print ("Total: %d GiB" % hdd.total / (2**30))
print ("Used: %d GiB" % hdd.used / (2**30))
print ("Free: %d GiB" % hdd.free / (2**30))
```

---

### **Python 3.3 and above:**

For Python 3.3 and above, you can use the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html) module, which has a [`disk_usage`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.disk_usage) function, returning a named tuple with the amounts of total, used and free space in your hard drive.

You can call the function as below and get all information about your disk's space:

```
import shutil

total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")

print("Total: %d GiB" % (total // (2**30)))
print("Used: %d GiB" % (used // (2**30)))
print("Free: %d GiB" % (free // (2**30)))
```

Output:

```
Total: 931 GiB
Used: 29 GiB
Free: 902 GiB
```

Comment: Good answer, but only calculates in gigabytes and the sizes of `total`, `used`, `free` could be anything. If you wanted to, you could go as far as using [hurry.filesize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hurry.filesize) which automatically handles this :)

Comment: @Wondercricket indeed, you 'll have to modify the divisor every time you  need different unit. Thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: only since python 3.3

Comment: This gives you the size of a *partition*, not the whole disk.

Comment: While solution might work for some, but doesn't work in anything below python 3.3.

Comment: I have 32GB sd card,  filesystem erased, it says 8GB ...

Answer (score 19):

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

```
import psutil

obj_Disk = psutil.disk_usage('/')

print (obj_Disk.total / (1024.0 ** 3))
print (obj_Disk.used / (1024.0 ** 3))
print (obj_Disk.free / (1024.0 ** 3))
print (obj_Disk.percent)
```

Comment: Let me suggest `float(1<<30)` rather than `(1024.0 ** 3)`

Answer (score 8):

The code is about right, but you're using wrong fields, which may give you the wrong results on a different system. The correct way would be:

```
>>> os.system('df -k /')
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       14846608 3247272  10945876  23% /

>>> disk = os.statvfs('/')
>>> (disk.f_bavail * disk.f_frsize) / 1024
10945876L
```

Comment: Does not work on Windows.

Comment: @lmocsi OP asked about macOS

Comment: The accepted solution works OS-independently

Comment: @lmocsi the accepted answer gives wrong results compared to `os.system('df -k /')`

Comment: What are the units?

Answer (score 3):

Printing out the type can help, when you don't know how to handle a function's result.

`print type(os.statvfs('/'))` returns `<type 'posix.statvfs_result'>`

That means it isn't a built in class instance like a string or int..

You can check what you can do with that instance with `dir(instance)`

`print dir(os.statvfs('/'))` prints all of it's the properties, functions, variables...

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__',
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__',
'__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__',
'__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'f_bavail', 'f_bfree', 'f_blocks',
'f_bsize', 'f_favail', 'f_ffree', 'f_files', 'f_flag', 'f_frsize',
'f_namemax', 'n_fields', 'n_sequence_fields', 'n_unnamed_fields']
```

By accessing one of the variables, like `os.statvfs('/').f_ffree` you can extract an integer.

Double check with `print type(os.statvfs('/').f_ffree)`,
it does print `<type 'int'>`.

Comment: `f_ffree` is a number of free file descriptors or something like that, nothing to do with the free space on the drive

Comment: @lenik No I got it from https://iterm2.com/python-api/examples/diskspace.html, I didn't see that you had written an actual answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner solution to show disk size in GiB based on the answers here:

```py
>>> import shutil

>>> [f"{y}: {x//(2**30)} GiB" for x, y in zip(shutil.disk_usage('/'), shutil.disk_usage('/')._fields)]
['total: 228 GiB', 'used: 14 GiB', 'free: 35 GiB']
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers in this thread only provide the disk size of the root partition. Here's my code for the people who need complete/entire hard disk size:

```
total = int()
used  = int()
free  = int()

for disk in psutil.disk_partitions():
    if disk.fstype:
        total += int(psutil.disk_usage(disk.mountpoint).total)
        used  += int(psutil.disk_usage(disk.mountpoint).used)
        free  += int(psutil.disk_usage(disk.mountpoint).free)

print(f'''    
    TOTAL DISK SPACE : {round(total / (1024.0 ** 3), 4)} GiB
    USED DISK SPACE  : {round(used / (1024.0 ** 3), 4)} GiB
    FREE DISK SPACE  : {round(free / (1024.0 ** 3), 4)} GiB
''')
```