# Use python to check for disk being io bound (high disk usage)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a system monitor that writes to a database for our server.

I am currently monitoring cpu/mem etc but am trying to get disk information such that we can tell if there are times that the disks are at their max and iobound for extended periods. The problem is that they are windows servers so there is no iowait(linux) as far as I can tell or I could use the psutil.cpu_times() option.

Is there a way to accomplish this on windows server using python?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get hard disk size in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929553/get-hard-disk-size-in-python)

Comment: No that is the disk space, I have looking for high usage like iowait on linux IE CPU is waiting to use the disk