# pyhton , Get size on disk of a file container

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I find the size on disk of a file container in Python? Please consider that I can't calculate the size on disk by using cluster size because the container may have empty space (see the picture)

```
size : 32,212,254,720 bytes

size on disk : 28,232,646,656 bytes
```

My operating system is Windows and using Python 3.8

[image: view the image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the Tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104080/how-do-i-check-file-size-in-python

Comment: @michael-d not work when object is "file container"

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "file container"?

Answer (score 1):

The "Size on disk" is not readily available, but needs to be [calculated based on dist block size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62602765/14536215). Since, `os.stats(path).st_blksize` wasn't available on my win10 machine, we need to [get it via ctypes call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494346/14536215) instead.

```py
import ctypes
from pathlib import Path
import math

fp = Path("E:/mylviing.JPG")

sectorsPerCluster = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
bytesPerSector = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
rootPathName = ctypes.c_wchar_p(fp.anchor)

ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetDiskFreeSpaceW(rootPathName,
    ctypes.pointer(sectorsPerCluster),
    ctypes.pointer(bytesPerSector),
    None,
    None,
)

cluster_size = bytesPerSector.value
size_on_disk = cluster_size * math.ceil(fp.stat().st_size * 1.0 / cluster_size)
print(size_on_disk)
```

Output: `208896`

My test file was

- size: 203 KB (208,498 bytes)
- Size on disk: 204 KB (208,896 bytes)

Comment: this not work when the object is a "file container", on my system :
sectorsPerCluster : 8
bytesPerSector : 512
rootPathName : 42152368
so size on disk must be 32212254720 bytes but it is 28,232,646,656 bytes (see the attached picture)